# is order of element in multiplicative group modulo n is upper bounded by n-1?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

That seems like it would make sense, but I can't think of any reasoning behind it. Could anyone tell me if it's the case, and if it is how can i justify it?

Comment: Follows immediately by the pigeonhole principle - see the Lemma in the linked dupe.

Comment: If you already know group theory then note that the order of $a$ is the size of the subgroup generated by $a$ which is clearly $\le $ the size of the whole group (which here is $\le n-\color{#c00}1$ since it omits nonunit $\color{#c00}0$ in $\Bbb Z_n)\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. The order of the multiplicative group modulo $n$ is $\varphi (n)\le n-1$.  The order of an element can't exceed the order of the group.

The upper bound is optimal as $\varphi (p)=p-1$ for $p$ prime, and in this case the group is cyclic.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (and PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).